# Packets being dropped by iptables

Tags: iptables, access-point

I am trying to create a Software Access Point in linux.

I followed the blog [here](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/).

Steps I performed:

1. Started dhcp server on wlan0.
2. Properly configured hostapd.conf
3. Enabled packet forwarding & masquerading.

Two commands executed regarding iptables:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

I enabled logging on iptables & I get this in everything.log

```
Jun 29 19:42:03 MBP-archlinux kernel: [10480.180356] IN=eth0 OUT=wlan0 MAC=c8:bc:c8:9b:c4:3c:00:13:80:40:cd:80:08:00 SRC=195.143.92.150 DST=10.0.0.3 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=38025 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=53570 WINDOW=46185 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jun 29 19:42:03 MBP-archlinux kernel: [10480.389102] IN=eth0 OUT=wlan0 MAC=c8:bc:c8:9b:c4:3c:00:13:80:40:cd:80:08:00 SRC=195.143.92.150 DST=10.0.0.3 LEN=308 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=14732 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=53570 WINDOW=46185 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Jun 29 19:42:03 MBP-archlinux kernel: [10480.389710] IN=eth0 OUT=wlan0 MAC=c8:bc:c8:9b:c4:3c:00:13:80:40:cd:80:08:00 SRC=195.143.92.150 DST=10.0.0.3 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=14988 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=53570 WINDOW=46185 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
Jun 29 19:42:03 MBP-archlinux kernel: [10480.621118] IN=eth0 OUT=wlan0 MAC=c8:bc:c8:9b:c4:3c:00:13:80:40:cd:80:08:00 SRC=195.143.92.150 DST=10.0.0.3 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=63378 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=53570 WINDOW=46185 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

I have almost no knowledge of iptables, all I did was through googling. So, can anyone help me in making me understand what wrong is happening here?

I have tried running tcpdump on wlan0 & http packets are being sent from wlan0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allow forwarding only from wlan0 to internet.

Try adding:

```
iptables --append FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

in order to accept response to forwarded traffic

Comment: Thank you, doing that removed the error. But, I am still not able to surf the internet. Attached here is the tcpdump log at wlan0 http://sprunge.us/iPcb . Any idea? Anyways, I will accept the answer as the original problem is solved.